# Issues with Ajax and Php posting

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Hi i have problem with my ajax and posting it to php. Basically when i click on a a:tag i want to delete that specific thing in the mysql database. This is how it is now:

**Javascript**

```
$('a.deletecross').bind('click', function() {
var image_id = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax/delete_picture.php",
data: image_id,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
}
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
  if(!logged_in()) {
    header('Location: /');
    exit();
}

    include '../init.php';

if(isset($_POST['image_id']) && image_exists($_POST['image_id']) ) {
   $image_id = $_POST['image_id'];
    delete_image($image_id);

}
?>
```

How i can i make it so the javascript funktion calls the php file and delete my image?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/delete_picture.php",
    data: {"image_id": image_id},
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    }
});
```

You have to send you post data as key/value pairs.

Comment: It doesn't work.. before i used the code 

           $.post('ajax/delete_picture.php', {image_id:image_id}, function(data)   {
But it doesnt work anymore though.

Answer (score 0):

#### Replace:

```
data: image_id,
```

With:

```
data: {"image_id": image_id},
```

See [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info!

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See `processData` option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the `traditional` setting (described below).

Comment: still doesnt call my php file.. :(

Comment: What happens in the network tab of Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug in Firefox?

Comment: And where is your PHP file? Is your PHP file in the right path?

Comment: yes i use to have `
           $.post('ajax/delete_picture.php', {image_id:image_id}, function(data)   {` and it worked like a charm, however now it doesnt

Comment: What is the error you are facing? Network / Console tabs results please

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (html){
} has no method 'done' admin.php:605
(anonymous function) admin.php:605
c.event.handle jquery.min.js:63
h.handle.o

Comment: WTH??? Omg!!! Something to do with your PHP code too. Can you post the full code?